# How do I center the start point of a line between the two clustered columns in a clustered stacked bar combo chart with overlayed line? (See picture)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How do I move the line from where it is to where I drew it? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the table? What is your X-axis?

Comment: Share some sample data to test

Answer (score 0):

1) Enter your data for the stacked columns, skipping one row between each row of data

2) Enter your data for the line in the blank rows.

Your table should look something like this:

[image]

3) Insert your combo chart, assigning Stack Column and Line to the appropriate data series.

4) You may not see the line at this point, right click on the chart and choose "Select Data

5) in the dialog box, click "Hidden and Empty Cells

6) Choose "Connect Data points with line.

[image]

7) Click "OK", you chart should look like this:

[image]

8) If you don't want extra the labels between columns, remove them from the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the simplified data and charts below. We're going to make an XY Scatter series of the Line data, not a Line series. The first column of line values provides the in-between spacing: the XY data will be plotted as if the first category (a) is 1, the second (b) is 2, etc. 1.5 will be plotted exactly in the middle of a and b.

Create a column chart with the column chart data (top left chart).

Copy the Line data, select the chart, and use Paste Special from the Paste dropdown on the Home tab of the ribbon, choosing the options New Series, Series in Columns, Category Labels in First Column, and Series Names in First Row. Excel adds the data as another column series (top right chart).

Right click on the added series, choose Change Series Chart Type from the pop-up menu, and select XY Scatter with Straight Lines and Markers (or without markers, but generally markers improve interpretation if there aren't hundreds of points). Assuming you didn't also uncheck the secondary axis box in the chart type dialog, you get the mess which is the bottom left chart.

Finally, select the added series, and format it to be on the primary axis (bottom right chart).

[image: Position Markers Between Column Categories]